# argparse argument with several sub-arguments, each takes values?

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to have some arguments as follows (just an example).

> **--some_arg** **opt_1** v1 **opt_2** v2_1 v2_2 v2_3 **opt_3** v3_1 v3_2

or in a more readable way, as follows.

> **--some_arg** **opt_1**=v1 **opt_2**=v2_1 v2_2 v2_3 **opt_3**=v3_1 v3_2

The values of **some_arg**, **otp_1**, **opt_2**, **opt_3** will be fed to the functions in the script. **opt_1**, **opt_2**, and **opt_3** could be mutually exclusive for some **some_arg**s or could be just non-exclusive optional sub-arguments for other **some_arg**s.

How to do this with python argparse? And if argparse cannot do it, are there other ways of doing this?

Comment: Your specification is not a good fit with `argparse`.

Comment: Just parse the `sys.argv` list, splitting it up on your key words.